# How to change position of the cursor using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function test(e)
{
}
```

Here how I call the function:

```
<img id="toolbarTitle" ondblclick="test(event)" width="16px" height="16px" src="../stdicons/GeomindIcons/toolbarIcon.png">
```

Any idea how can I change position of the cursor in the test finction?

Comment: Very unclear, *change position of the cursor* to where?

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/pointerlock/

Comment: you mean texarea or textbox ?